# What is “app_exception” event in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

What is “app_exception” event in Firebase?

ScreenShot:

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBkaT.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en), it's when your app crashes or throws an exception.